# Adding XML layout to custom ViewGroup at run-time - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater

Is it possible to add a XML layout to custom extended `ViewGroup` at runtime?

I tried adding the layout using `LayoutInflator.inflate(...)` method but it only returns the root node of the xml layout. Is there any way to inflate the full layout and add it to the `ViewGroup`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a view at any position using the index argument of [view.addView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29). When you create a new instance of your ViewGroup, you should be able to call:

```
myCustomViewGroup.addView(View childView, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params);
```

To get your childView, use [LayoutInflator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28int,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) (or findViewById(int))

```
View childView = layoutInflater.inflate(XmlResourceId, myCustomViewGroup);
```

My syntax may not be exactly right but this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Tried inflating layout but it is giving only root layout not containing the child components contained in the layout.

Comment: To get the child elements you can now use childView.findViewById(R.id.myid). Please append your code to your original post so I can see what you are trying to achieve.